# Why does `nuxt generate` put the commons.js file into dist/node_modules/

Tags: nuxt.js

For good measure, I delete the "dist" folder before running `yarn generate`.

As expected, Nuxt generates a build and puts the files in the "dist" folder. What's not expected, is that it creates a "node_modules" folder INSIDE of "dist/_nuxt" and puts the commons.js file inside of `dist/_nuxt/node_modules`.

When I run `yarn start` everything works as expected. The problem arises when I commit "dist" to Git. The project's .gitignore file excludes "node_modules" and consequently the commons.js file does not get pushed to the repository. I can fix this by editing the .gitignore file but I am concerned there is something else going on and that feels like a hack.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug in [version 2.14.1](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/commit/c30499d7e02cd6d8b51d97ee7d7a537d8a59f63b) of Nuxt which was released Aug 4, 2020. Resolved the issue by reverting to v2.14.0.

Comment: Created a bug report here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7901